# Adobe Flash: How to read multiple lines from a .txt file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a simple flash animation that displays text in a textField(textBox?).

```
var fl_TextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var fl_TextURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./liveStatus.txt");

fl_TextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fl_CompleteHandler);

function fl_CompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var textData:String = new String(fl_TextLoader.data);
    trace(textData);

    text_feed_1.text_feed_1_text.text = textData;
}
```

However, when the text file has multiple lines, the text that gets displayed only contains the first line of that file, while the "trace" method displays everything in the console output. So I wonder how to display the additional lines from that text file in the textField.
Also, it would be great if these lines can be parsed into a string array. That would be even better because I can then manipulate the lines of that file.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the "multiline" (and maybe "wordWrap") value from your Textfield to true.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html

An to parse your string in a array you could use the split method from `String` like so:

```
var linesArray:Array = fl_TextLoader.data.split("\n");
```

\n = new line char. ("\r" or "\r\n" might alos do the trick depending on the encoding of your text file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works. I have an additional question, how do I adjust the line spacing of a given textField? I tried textfield.textHeight, but turns out it is read-only. Thank you!

Comment: @FrozenLand See `TextFormat::leading` property, apparently you need this one to be set for a nonzero value to have spaces between lines.